# flask-marshmallow validation on field data not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

Hi I made my dto something like this

```
class MyRequestDto(ma.Schema):
    @pre_load
    def wrap_data(self, in_data, **kwargs):
        return {"rooms": in_data}


    rooms = ma.Dict(ma.String, ma.Dict(ma.Integer, ma.String))
```

**and I want to send request something like this :**

```
{   
    "1faf8f07-2977-180e-7bc2-b5adf8badasda": {"student_id":11210687,"room_id":"100"}
}
```

**but getting error like this**

```
{
    "rooms": {
        "1faf8f07-2977-180e-7bc2-b5adf8badasda": {
            "value": {
                "student_id": {
                    "key": [
                        "Not a valid integer."
                    ]
                },
                "room_id": {
                    "key": [
                        "Not a valid integer."
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I can do to pass data correctly in the required format?

Comment: Your `ma.Dict(ma.Integer, ma.String)` defines keys as `int`. Set `ma.Dict(ma.String, ma.String)`, or convert values to `int` and set `ma.Dict(ma.String, ma.Integer)`

Comment: @VladSiv thanks for replying sir , I want to send `student_id` as integer I updated my question that was mistak. now what should I do ?

Comment: Change `room_id` to `int` and set `ma.Dict(ma.String, ma.Integer)` instead of `ma.Dict(ma.Integer, ma.String)`

Comment: but sir @VladSiv  I want  to send `room_id` as string :( . is this not possible to pass `student_id` as integer and `room_id` as string at same time  ?

Comment: You'll have to define a custom field then, take a look at: [Custom Fields](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class)

Comment: Updated the answer to give you different examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer` type supports cast.

From the [documentation](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/marshmallow.fields.html#marshmallow.fields.Integer):

```
class marshmallow.fields.Integer(*, strict: bool = False, **kwargs)[source]
    An integer field.
    Parameters
            strict – If True, only integer types are valid. Otherwise, any value castable to int is valid.
            kwargs – The same keyword arguments that Number receives.
```

So try:

```
class MyRequestDto(Schema):
    @pre_load
    def wrap_data(self, in_data, **kwargs):
        return {"rooms": in_data}

    rooms = Dict(String, Dict(String, Integer))
```

It will automatically handle the `str` for `room_id`.

If you want to keep `room_id` as `str` then you need to define a [Custom Field](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/custom_fields.html#creating-a-field-class).

Example:

```py
class CustomField(Field):
    def _serialize(self, value, attr, obj, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(value, (str, int)):
            return value
        raise ValidationError("Value is not int or str")

    def _deserialize(self, value, attr, data, **kwargs):
        if isinstance(value, (str, int)):
            return value
        raise ValidationError("Value is not int or str")


class MyRequestDto(Schema):
    @pre_load
    def wrap_data(self, in_data, **kwargs):
        return {"rooms": in_data}

    rooms = Dict(String, Dict(String, CustomField))
```